# pandas.read_csv: how do I parse two columns as datetimes in a hierarchically-indexed CSV?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a CSV file that, simplified, looks like this:

```
X,,Y,,Z,
Date,Time,A,B,A,B
2017-01-21,01:57:49.390,0,1,2,3
2017-01-21,01:57:50.400,4,5,7,9
2017-01-21,01:57:51.410,3,2,4,1
```

The first two columns are date and time. When I do"

```
pandas.read_csv('foo.csv', header=[0,1])
```

I get the following DataFrame:

```
            X Unnamed: 1_level_0  Y Unnamed: 3_level_0  Z Unnamed: 5_level_0
         Date               Time  A                  B  A                  B
0  2017-01-21       01:57:49.390  0                  1  2                  3
1  2017-01-21       01:57:50.400  4                  5  7                  9
2  2017-01-21       01:57:51.410  3                  2  4                  1
```

Ignoring the annoying unnamed entries in the columns for now, I'd like to combine the first two columns into a single datetime. So I tried using the parse_dates argument:

```
pandas.read_csv('foo.csv', header=[0,1], parse_dates={'datetime': [0,1]})
```

But all I get from this is a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 401, in _read
    data = parser.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 939, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1585, in read
    names, data = self._do_date_conversions(names, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1364, in _do_date_conversions
    self.index_names, names, keep_date_col=self.keep_date_col)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2737, in _process_date_conversion
    data_dict.pop(c)
KeyError: "('X', 'Date')"
```

I'm not sure why it's hitting a `KeyError` on `('X', 'Date')`, since those are definitely present in the columns. I don't really know if this is a bug in `pandas` that I should report (I'm using 0.19.2), or if I'm just not understanding something. Any ideas?

Comment: yup, seems like a bug. I played around with the various options, and the one that might work best in your situation is to specify columns 0 & 1 as the index, and parse the index as a date, ie. `pd.read_csv('foo.csv', header=[0,1], parse_dates=True, index_cols[0,1])`. Reporting this issue would be a good idea.

Comment: I have submitted a PR for this issue.  See my answer.

Comment: Update: PR has been approved for release `0.20.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around if needed:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

# read in the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', header=[0, 1])

# get a label for the funky column names
date_label, time_label = tuple(df.columns.values)[0:2]

# merge the columns into a single datetime
dates = [
    dt.datetime.strptime('T'.join(ts) + '000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
    for ts in zip(df[date_label], df[time_label])]

# save the new column
df['DateTime'] = pd.Series(dates).values
```

**Update:**

I have submitted a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15376) and a [pull request](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/15378) for this issue.  In [response](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15376#issuecomment-279227905) to the bug, [jreback](https://github.com/jreback) (pandas lead maintainer) gave a fairly detailed response about issues with the multi-level header from the example.  I think you are already aware of these issues, but you may want to read what he wrote.  At the end of the response he had this bit that may provide a work around:

*Making a single level is just not useful in a multi-level frame. I would probably do this:*

```
In [25]: pandas.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=0, skiprows=1, parse_dates={'datetime':[0,1]})
Out[25]: 
                 datetime  A  B  A.1  B.1
0 2017-01-21 01:57:49.390  0  1    2    3
1 2017-01-21 01:57:50.400  4  5    7    9
2 2017-01-21 01:57:51.410  3  2    4    1
```